# What determines window.frame?

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I've been working on updating a few apps to support iPhone 5. They've had some layout issues that might be explained by the UIWindow always having the frame of an iPhone 5 regardless of the device it is run on. For a universal application for  example the frame of the UIWindow gets set to (0, 0, 320, 568) even on an iPad. I am wondering what causes this and if this is really what I should be concerned with.

Comment: How are you determining the size of the window?

Comment: Have you checked the target devices? and added splash images for targeted devices?

Comment: I have splash screens and icons provided for every applicable device and I've double checked the target devices and it looks like it should. I also just ran a test on the simulators for the universal app where I put a breakpoint at the very beginning of -applicationDidFinishLaunching: and entered "po window" into the debugger for iPhone 4, iPhone 5 and iPad Retina and for all three the output was the same, saying "frame = (0 0; 320 568);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never checked this myself on universal applications, however make sure that:

1. The window is already part of the view hierarchy. A newly created window won't help you with determining the size (you say you log `frame` "at the very beginning of -applicationDidFinishLaunching:").
2. The `frame` is just an accessor which merges `bounds` and `center` properties. It doesn't work correctly if transforms are applied to the view (window). However, with a window, it's typical that a transform is applied.

The iOS drawing code for a window looks similar to the following:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
     -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
     -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

[[window layer] renderInContext:context];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

(See [Technical Note QA1703](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html))

You can see that the final `frame` size is determined from `bounds` and `transform`. If you do some experiments, you can see that, for example, the keyboard window never changes bounds, even when device orientation is changed. The size change between portrait and landscape orientations is determined by the `transform`.

In general, `window.rootViewController.bounds` is the way to go.

Comment: By part of hte view hierearchy do yo umean calling -makeKeyandVisible? I tried putting checks after that and it's the same. It seems that having a MainWindow.xib is the root of my problems as it stays in just one size. Changing simulated metrics also changes its size. I've read that it's an old practice to have these xib files so I'm gonna try making the window programmatically instead. Thanks for the piece of technical info about the drawing.

Comment: @RickardWesterlund I am interested in one thing - can you confirm that the window size will stay the same the whole time? For example, when `viewDidLayout` is called on the view controller, will the window still have the same size? Anyway, there is almost no situation, when window size should interest you.

Comment: Yes, the window size appears to stay the same. The window size does seem to matter for the touch input, anything outside the window will not receive any inputs. Also, when rotating I can see the window because four black boxes on each side of it's frame will outline it. It seems that the root view controller's view is not set by the window size though, but that's a different issue. Right now the code sort of works when I make the UIWindow programmatically, it's just not very pretty.